# Why is the order "is not" instead of the more rationally intuitive "not is"?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

1. He not is.
2. He is not.

Using the second method, you have to listen to the third word 100% of the time, instead of only when "not" is used.

Comment: Because English is not symbolic logic? If you reversed it, you'd have to wait longer to hear the verb. Also, *not* modifies the object of the sentence, not the verb: ***He is*** *(not hungry).*

Comment: @JasonBassford Just to clarify, "hungry" is a subject complement, not an object. And "not" negates the verb, not the subject complement.

Comment: @Gustavson I disagree. Not with the verbiage within the syntactic vocabulary you're using (although it's a different discourse space), but with the particular method of analysis you're choosing with respect to what I'm trying to say. In particular, I am affirming a *positive* of a *negative* aspect. Which is why I used the parentheses in exactly the way I did. Had I meant to affirm a *negative* of a *positive* aspect, I would have used *he (**is not**) hungry*, which is a totally different interpretation. In the way I used it, it does not negate the verb at all.

Comment: Jason, as usual, is quite correct. You can think of *He is not* as a prefix to the rest of the sentence about precisely *what* He is not. He is not hungry; He is not a unicorn; the fun never ends.

Comment: *"Using the second method, you have to listen to the third word 100% of the time, instead of only when "not" is used."* - Are you suggesting that with different syntax you could somehow avoid listening to some of the words? Selectively block your ears for parts of the sentence, or skip over those words when reading?

Comment: For "not" to refer to "hungry", a special context is needed, for example: *He wants something, but he's not hungry -- just thirsty*. "not" will negate the verb in other contexts: *Is he hungry? / No, he isn't.*

Comment: He cannot.
He could not.
He dare not.
He did not.
He does not.
He may not.
He might not.
He must not.
He ought not.
He need not.
He shall not.
He should not.
He will not.
He would not.

Comment: @nnnnnn, you don't know where it's going until the next word, so the interpretation is more difficult than it needs to be

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, there is a difference between (1) *he is not a unicorn* and (2) *he is a not-unicorn*. When I used parentheses to say *he is (not hungry)*, it was in the same conceptual sense as *he is (a not-unicorn)*.

Comment: @Jason Bassford An example of when this is problematic: "-- are not representative of, or fulfill the ideal of, --". It would make sense if it were "-- not are representative of, or fulfil the ideal of, --". Yes, you could fix it with a perfectly fine *workaround*, but it doesn't make sense that "not" should come after "are".

Comment: @user378171 No matter which way you want to make English work, extra words will still need to be read in some contexts.

Comment: @Jason Bassford No, that's not true; if you used "not are" you would not need to use extra words in some contexts.

Comment: @user378171 I still don't see why "are not" should be inferior to "not are." In order to have some kind of objective analysis in support of your proposal, you'd have to show metrics that indicate (1) using one less word mid-sentence actually is useful and (2) out of all constructions used, one less word actually would be used in more constructions if we were to change the order. But even if you could do that, you're talking about something that's evolved either arbitrarily or without a clearly known historical rationale. I don't see how this question can be answered objectively.

Comment: @user378171 *You not …* What? What follows *not*? Even assuming it were idiomatic, it could be *are*, *throw*, *eat*, or any verb. With *you are*, we know what the verb is with only 2 words. With *you not*, it takes at least 3 words to get to the verb.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I get the sense that "He is not running" is used to make a negative statement, rather than a positive one. And yet "He is" "not running" is a positive statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things going on here even for something so simple as where to place negation. There are general linguistic things going on, plus English specific things.

In general, anything goes in grammar. OK not -anything-, but quite a lot you wouldn't expect. Some languages have Subject Verb-Object order (or SOV):

> The man catches the rabbit.

This seems entirely logical to me, and anything else is stark raving lunacy. Except some languages are Subject-Object-Verb. Classically, Vulgar Latin has this:

> homo leporem capit. ("Man rabbit catches")

SVO and SOV are the most common languages in the world, but there are even VSO languages, like Irish.

> Glacann an fear an coinín ("Catches the man the rabbit")

(as the Germans say "Die Iren sind irren").

The point of this so far is that the order of pieces can vary. None are illogical. It's in some sense a style choice that just happens to be preserved in a community so it feels like it is eternal truth.

So whether you put the negative marker first or second, -something- is going to be left unsaid.

1. "He is..." what is it? "He is not..." OK whatever it is it's not that, but what is it still? That's the current way.
2. "He not..." what's going to not happen? "He not is..." OK, but still what is it that is not?

---

It kinda turns out that English does -both- kinds of negation.

> The man **does not** catch the rabbit.

The marker for negation here comes before like you desired [(that pesky 'does' has an interesting history called 'do-support')](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support). But that is not 'logical' it's just one way of doing things.

French also has interesting negation. It used to put 'ne', essentially the same thing as English 'not', in front of the verb.

> L'homme n'attrape pas le lapin

(the 'e' in 'ne' is elided because it's easy to do). But what is that 'pas'? It literally means English 'step' and is sort of like 'not one step' as an intensifier.

And over the years, colloquial French has tended to -drop- the 'ne' entirely. You'll hear important people in the news saying

> L'homme attrape pas le lapin.

So even though 'pas' literally means 'step', it doesn't matter what it literally means because it is the only thing that marks negation in the sentence so it totally means 'not' now.

That's pretty much it. You just gotta get used to the idea that:

- Language wasn't designed by one person who is trying to optimize one of your pet criteria (let's say 'continuous partial prefix interpretation'?)
- Language changes. Styles change, order of words change, vocabulary changes.
- Language does a bunch of other crazy stuff you wouldn't expect. You just get used to it.